# ConstraintLayout change constraint programmatically to movable view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have `floating action button` which is movable horizontally. Each time when user drag `floating action button` I send x coordinate to my activity and based on that I can do two things:
1)

```
   @Override
        public void update(float x) {
            //first try
            view.getLayoutParams().width = (int) x + fab.getWidth() / 2;
            view.requestLayout();
    }
```

This works! I update view width to floating action button x position. 
However it would be great if I could do the same with `ConstraintLayout` (basically add view constraint to floating action button like so).

```
@Override
    public void update(float x) {

        //second try
        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(rootLayout);
        constraintSet.clear(fab.getId());
        constraintSet.connect(view.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, fab.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, 0); // view is green view
        constraintSet.applyTo(rootLayout);
    }
```

However this is not working for me. Why? I add my xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#2abab8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: why don't you bind green view to FAB? so if FAB will change it's position - view automatically change it's position to

Comment: reverse it and try. Bind the view to FAB.